# java sql syntax error

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans

i'm writing this code to get the values from textfields and update a register in my database.. but it shows "Syntax error : Encountered "\" at line 1,column 196
and when i select another row from the jtable the column number in syntax error change..Can anyone tell me what's the wrong here and how can i fix it
here's the code :

```
String up = "UPDATE BENEFICTOR SET ID='"+T1.getText().toString()+"', FID='"+T2.getText().toString()+"', FULLNAME='"+T3.getText().toString()+"', GENDER='"+T4.getSelectedItem().toString()+"', IDNUM='"+T5.getText().toString()+"', STATUS='"+T6.getSelectedItem().toString()+"', ORIGINALAREA='"+T7.getText().toString()+"', RECENTAREA='"+T8.getText().toString()+"', EVAL='"+T9.getSelectedItem().toString()+"', PHONENYMBER1='"+T10.getText().toString()+"', PHONENUMBER2='"+T11.getText().toString()+"', SITUATION='"+T12.getText().toString()+"', VISIT='"+T13.getText().toString()+" WHERE ID="+T1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing or NetBeans??? You have an SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of that code and use a `PreparedStatement`. The `PreparedStatement` will replace each "?" for you with the related parameter and use the proper delimiters:

To get you started:

```
String sql = "UPDATE BENEFICTOR SET ID = ?, FID = ?, .... WHERE ID = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, T1.getText() );
stmt.setString( 2, T2.getText() );
...
stmt.setString( ?, T1.getText() );
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: Should i put it as a question marks or fill it with values ?

Comment: It gives me right now : At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized

Comment: So make sure you initialize them all. I only gave you the code for the first two. I don't know how many parameters you have. You need to code the entire SQL statement. I'm not going to do it all for you.

Comment: Excuse me i mean..should i put question marks as you did ?

Answer (score 0):

assemble sql like this is not smart,you have just miss a ','

```
VISIT='"+T13.getText().toString()+" WHERE ID="+T1.getText().toString();
```

and the other careless behaviour is ...

```
"UPDATE BENEFICTOR SET ID='"+T1.getText().toString()+"', 
" WHERE ID="+T1.getText().toString();
```

focus on the quotes that you added at first.